# ¿Por qué no se logra iterar el array con sus respectivos elementos mediante forEach?

Tags: javascript, array, bucles, foreach

Tengo un array de elementos que el usuario va llenando al ingresar los datos por prompt, pero al querer iterarlo con forEach y mostrarlo por la pantalla, no logro hacerlo, aún cuando intenté de varias maneras.

```
const colores = []
    class Color {
      constructor(producto, cantidad, precio) {
        this.producto = producto
        this.cantidad = cantidad
        this.precio = precio
      }
      info() {
        return `De ${this.producto} tenemos ${this.cantidad} y el valor es de $${this.precio}x talla`
  }
}

while (colores.length < 2) {
  let producto = prompt('Ingrese el nombre del producto').toLowerCase()
  let cantidad = prompt('Ingrese la cantidad del stock')
  let precio = prompt('ingrese el valor del producto')
  if (!isNaN(cantidad) && !isNaN(precio)) {
    colores.push(new Color(producto, cantidad, precio))
  }
}

const mostrarInventario = () => {
  console.log(colores)
}

colores.forEach(function(elemento, index) {
  document.write(`<li id="${index}">${elemento}</li>`)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta en tu código llamar al método info de cada elemento. En el ciclo debes insertar:

```
document.write(`<li id="${index}">${elemento.info()}</li>`)
```

Te adjunto tu código corregido:

```js
const colores = []

class Color {
  constructor(producto, cantidad, precio) {
    this.producto = producto
    this.cantidad = cantidad
    this.precio = precio
  }

  info() {
    return `De ${this.producto} tenemos ${this.cantidad} y el valor es de $${this.precio}x talla`
  }
}

while (colores.length < 2) {
  let producto = prompt('Ingrese el nombre del producto').toLowerCase()
  let cantidad = prompt('Ingrese la cantidad del stock')
  let precio = prompt('ingrese el valor del producto')
  if (!isNaN(cantidad) && !isNaN(precio)) {
    colores.push(new Color(producto, cantidad, precio))
  }
}

const mostrarInventario = () => {
  console.log(colores)
}

colores.forEach(function(elemento, index) {
  document.write(`<li id="${index}">${elemento.info()}</li>`)
})
```